# Adding comma in all the rows except last row in python csv reader?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, rows

I need to add a comma mark in all the rows of a csv file except the last row in python. I have tried but comma mark is also added in the last row. How to discard comma mark in the last row of the csv file?

I am reading the csv file which is having almost 3000 rows and 2 columns (I am appending each merged row (for 2 columns) within inverted comma marks. I have tried but st-rucking. Any help is deeply appreciated.

The code:

```
import csv, string, nltk
def process_rs():
    with open('rs1.csv') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       next(reader, None)
       global raw_text
       with open('raw_reqs.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f1:
          for row in reader:
              raw_text = ('"'+' '.join(row)+'.'+'"'+', ')
              f1.write(raw_text)
              print(raw_text)
process_rs()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `for` loop to something like this:

```
with open('raw_reqs.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f1:
    rows = ('"{}."'.format(' '.join(row)) for row in reader)
    raw_text = ', '.join(rows)
    f1.write(raw_text)
```

Just notice though that `rows` is getting a generator, which implies that it can be iterated only once. Change it to a list comprehension, might you need to use `rows` content more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df[:-1].to_csv('newFile', sep = ',')
#adding the last row without separator:
with open('newFile', 'a') as f:
    df[-1:].to_csv(f,header=f.tell()==0, sep = ' ')
```

You can read more about the methods options https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: sorry, I forgot about the last line. You can use the indexing of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading all lines, discarding the last, then parsing the rest, like this:

```py
import numpy as np

with open('file.csv', 'r') as fid:
    lines = fid.readlines()

# discard the last row:
lines = lines[:-1]

# parse the rest into an array
a     = np.array( [line.strip('\n').split(',')  for line in lines], dtype=float )
```